# Does the 'closure of the interior' equal the 'interior of the closure'?

Tags: general-topology

My answer is *no* because, $\mathbb{Q}^o = \emptyset$ and so $\overline{(\mathbb{Q}^o)} = \emptyset$ but $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$ and so $\big(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\,\big)^o = \mathbb{R}$.

Is my example correct?

Comment: This is the first example that comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, your example is correct.

Comment: It doesn't need to be so ill-behaved though. For example, take $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. The closure of the interior is $[0,1]$, but the interior of the closure is $(0,1)$.

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. Note that the closure of any set is closed, while the interior of any set is open. The only two sets (in $\mathbb R$) which are both closed and open are the empty set and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: **Attention** The examples are corrects if you have usual topology

Answer (score 3):

Another simple example may be [0,1]. Its interior is (0,1), whose closure is [0,1] again.
Now, closure of [0,1] is [0,1], whose interior is (0,1)! Your question may be more interesting, if you wanted all subsets of **R**,say, for which the terms closure and interior are commutative! Then your example of **Q**,the irrationals, the Cantor set and my example of any closed interval work.

Comment: I didnot notice the comment of Chris while I was typing my answer!