# does the closure of interior of a set equal to closure of this set?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Does the $\text{Cl}(\text{Int} A)=\text{Cl}(A)$?  Here "Cl" denotes closure, "Int" denotes interior.

That is not a duplicate of the question of "does the closure of interior of a set equal t the *interior of* closure of this set".

I have a problem when trying to understand the Sanov's theorem in 
https://blogs.princeton.edu/sas/2013/10/10/lecture-3-sanovs-theorem/

about the Sanov's theorem.
$-\underset{Q\in int \Gamma}{\inf} D(Q||P)\leq \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\inf}\frac{1}{n}\log P\leq -\underset{Q\in cl \Gamma}{\inf}D(Q||P)$

inf over $\Gamma$ equlas to inf over $cl \Gamma$, should the left hand side and right hand side be equal?

Thank you！

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is generally no. For example, a closed set could have empty interior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the 'closure of the interior' equal the 'interior of the closure'?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144544/does-the-closure-of-the-interior-equal-the-interior-of-the-closure)

Comment: @avid19 This one doesn't have the "interior of the closure" part.

Comment: @avid19: No, it is obviously not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @MattSamuel thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Look at example of $A=\mathbb{Q}$.

$\overline{A^o}=\emptyset$ but $\overline{A}=\mathbb{R}$, where $\overline{A}$ is closure of $A$ and $A^o$ is interior of $A$.

Comment: Thank you！ This is a good example!